# GitHub Actions 'workflow_run' event how to edit UI workflow name dynamically?

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I have three workflows on Github Actions `ci.yml`, `release.yml` and `cd.yml` when `release.yml` ends its execution, automatically `cd.yml` starts with a workflow_run, but the message that appears on the Github UI is the name of the workflow. I want to know if there's a way to dynamically set display name on the Github UI based on maybe a commit or a branch.

I pushed a tag `v0.0.3` with the commit message of "initial layout" and when that workflow ends, the cd workflow starts, but on the UI appears as "cd" I want to change dynamically the title of that workflow from the yaml file so it appears like "v0.0.3" instead of "cd", is there a way to do this?
[image]

ci.yml

```yaml
name: ci

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master, dev, 'feature/**', 'bugfix/**', 'hotfix/**' ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master, dev ]
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  lint:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        go-version: [ 1.18.x ]
        platform: [ ubuntu-latest ]
    name: lint files
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.platform }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-go@v3
        with:
          go-version: ${{ matrix.go-version }}
      - name: golangci-lint
        uses: golangci/golangci-lint-action@v2.5.2
        with:
          version: latest

  test:
    needs: [ lint ]
    strategy:
      matrix:
        go-version: [ 1.18.x ]
        platform: [ ubuntu-latest ]
    name: test go app
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.platform }}
    steps:
      - name: setup go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v3
        with:
          go-version: ${{ matrix.go-version }}
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: test go app
        run: go test -v ./...

  build:
    needs: [ lint ]
    strategy:
      matrix:
        go-version: [ 1.18.x ]
        platform: [ ubuntu-latest ]
    name: build go app
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.platform }}
    steps:
    - name: setup go
      uses: actions/setup-go@v3
      with:
        go-version: ${{ matrix.go-version }}
    - name: checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: build artifacts
      run: |
        go build -o bin/app ./cmd/...
```

release.yml

```yaml
name: ci release

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*'

jobs:
  ci:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/ci.yml

  release:
    name: release / create github release
    needs: [ci]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: success() && startsWith(github.ref_name, 'v') && github.ref_type == 'tag' && github.event_name == 'push'
    outputs:
      RELEASE_URL: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: create release
        uses: actions/create-release@master
        id: create_release
        with:
          draft: false
          prerelease: true
          release_name: ${{ github.ref_name }}
          tag_name: ${{ github.ref_name }}
          body_path: CHANGELOG.md
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}  # ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}

  build_artifact:
    needs: [ release ]
    strategy:
      matrix:
        go-version: [ 1.18.x ]
        platform: [ ubuntu-latest ]
    name: build artifact
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.platform }}
    steps:
    - name: setup go
      uses: actions/setup-go@v3
      with:
        go-version: ${{ matrix.go-version }}
    - name: checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: build artifacts
      run: |
        go build -o bin/app ./cmd/...
        zip bin.zip ./bin/app
    - name: upload linux artifact
      uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
      with:
        upload_url: ${{ needs.release.outputs.RELEASE_URL }}
        asset_path: ./bin.zip
        asset_name: app
        asset_content_type: application/zip
```

cd.yml

```yaml
name: cd

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [ "ci release" ]
    types:
      - completed
    branch: [ master ]

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: "deploy to heroku"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }} 
      - name: Terraform validate
        run: terraform validate
      - name: Terraform init - apply
        run: |
          cd terraform
          export HEROKU_API_KEY=${{ secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY }} HEROKU_EMAIL=${{ secrets.HEROKU_EMAIL }}
          terraform init -backend-config="conn_str=${{ secrets.TERRAFORM_BE }}"
          terraform apply -var build_version=${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }} --auto-approve
```

Comment: I am trying to do the same, have you found a solution?

Comment: No, sorry. I haven't

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`run-name`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#run-name) property for the workflow.